# NullPointerException when trying to remove a Node from a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm creating a function that removes a node from a linked list but it is giving me a NullPointerException. I tried to check to see if the next one is null but it is giving me that error there now.

Remove function:

```
 private boolean remove(Node aNode)
    {
        Node prevNode, nextNode;
        prevNode = this.getPrevious(aNode);
        if(aNode.getNext()==null){ // NullPointerException
            return false;
        }
        else{
            nextNode = aNode.getNext();
            prevNode.setNext(nextNode);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Node class:

```
public class Node
{
    ///////////////////////////////////
    //           Properties          //
    ///////////////////////////////////
    private Object myData;
    private Node myNext;

    ///////////////////////////////////
    //             Methods           //
    ///////////////////////////////////

    /**
     *  Default constructor for a node with null
     *  data and pointer to a next node
     */
    public Node()
    {
        myData = null;
        myNext = null;
    }

    /**
     *  Constructor for a node with some object for
     *  its data and null for a pointer to a next node
     *
     *  <pre>
     *  pre:  a null node
     *  post: a node with some object for its data and
     *        null for a pointer to a next node
     *  </pre>
     *
     *  @param datum an object for the node's data
     */
    public Node(Object datum)
    {
        myData = datum;
        myNext = null;
    }

    /**
     *  Constructor for a node with some object for 
     *  its data and a pointer to another node
     *
     *  <pre>
     *  pre:  a null node
     *  post: a node with some object for its data and
     *        a pointer to a next node
     *  </pre>
     *
     *  @param datum an object for the node's data
     *  @param next the node that this node points to
     */
    public Node(Object datum, Node next)
    {
        myData = datum;
        myNext = next;
    }

    // Accessor methods
    public void setData(Object datum)
    {
        myData = datum;
    }

    public Object getData()
    {
        return myData;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next)
    {
        myNext = next;
    }

    public Node getNext()
    {
        return myNext;
    }
}
```

Here is the main section of the full Linked List class

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LinkedList linkedList;
        Node testNode1, testNode2, testNode10, foundNode;
        boolean success;

        linkedList = new LinkedList();

        // Test "inList()" method
        testNode1 = new Node(new Integer(1));
        testNode2 = new Node(new Integer(2));
        testNode10 = new Node(new Integer(10));

       // System.out.println("In List = "+linkedList.inList(null));
        linkedList.printList();
        foundNode = linkedList.findNode(new Integer(2));
        System.out.println("Found node "+foundNode);
        success = linkedList.remove(null);
        System.out.println("Success = "+success);
        success = linkedList.remove(testNode1);
        System.out.println("Success = "+success);
        linkedList.addFirst(testNode1);
        success = linkedList.remove(testNode1);
        System.out.println("Success = "+success);
        linkedList.printList();
       // System.out.println("In List = "+linkedList.inList(null));
       // System.out.println("In List = "+linkedList.inList(testNode1));
       // System.out.println("In List = "+linkedList.inList(testNode2));

        // Test "addLast()" and "addFirst()" methods
        linkedList.addLast(new Node(new Integer(1)));
        linkedList.addLast(new Node(new Integer(2)));
        linkedList.addLast(new Node(new Integer(3)));
        linkedList.addLast(testNode10);
        foundNode = linkedList.findNode(new Integer(2));
        System.out.println("Found node "+foundNode.toString());
        linkedList.printList();

        Node testNode;
        testNode = linkedList.getPrevious(foundNode);
        System.out.println(testNode.getData());
        System.exit(0);

        success = linkedList.insertBefore("H", testNode1);
        System.out.println("Success = "+success);
        linkedList.printList();
        linkedList.addFirst(new Node(new Integer(1)));
        linkedList.addFirst(new Node(new Integer(2)));
        linkedList.addFirst(new Node(new Integer(3)));
        linkedList.printList();
        success = linkedList.insertBefore("A", testNode10);
        System.out.println("Success = "+success);
        linkedList.printList();

        // Test "remove()"
        success = linkedList.remove(testNode1);
        System.out.println("Success = "+success);
        success = linkedList.remove(testNode2);
        System.out.println("Success = "+success);
        success = linkedList.remove(testNode10);
        System.out.println("Success = "+success);
        linkedList.printList();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you creating `aNode`

Comment: What class is removeNode part of?  What is the `this` you're referring to?

Comment: May not solve the problem, but I'd say it's a good idea to check that aNode isn't null before using it.

Comment: Where do you call `remove()` from?

Answer (score 3):

You get that exception because `aNode` is `null` and you try to call a `null` object's `getNext()` method, which means at some point, you called `remove(null)`. Since you don't show us where you call `remove()`, it is impossible to tell, but you either need to make sure that doesn't happen, or check explicitly if `aNode` is `null` before attempting to call methods on it.

If you aren't *expecting* `aNode` to be `null` but it is, you should double check your code to make sure you are actually implementing everything properly, as this is a good indication that something is going wrong elsewhere in your algorithm.

Update (looking at your edited question with new code): You have:

```
success = linkedList.remove(null);
```

That is the source of your problem; my above answer covers your options for fixing the exception.

**In the future you need to examine (and post) the entire stack trace of your exception, which would clearly identify that line of code.**

Answer (score 1):

You must be calling remove with aNode set to null. There is no other explanation for this behavior.

It is good practise to assert aNode != null if you do not expect it to be.

Comment: +1 for mentioning assertions. To the reader: Take care, however, to not use `assert` like a plain old `if` for checking conditions; assertions should be used to test/self-document assumptions that you are making that, if not true, break your code and/or indicate broken code elsewhere (i.e. an assertion failure indicates a bug).

Answer (score 1):

It could only mean that `aNode` itself is null